# Conditional Union in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

Currently I've a query as follows:

```
-- Query 1
SELECT
    acc_code, acc_name, alias, LAmt, coalesce(LAmt,0) AS amt 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        acc_code, acc_name, alias, 
        (SELECT 
            (SUM(cr_amt)-SUM(dr_amt)) 
        FROM 
            ledger_mcg l
        WHERE 
            (l.acc_code LIKE a.acc_code + '.%' OR l.acc_code=a.acc_code) 
        AND 
            fy_id=1 
        AND
            posted_date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2011-06-02') AS LAmt 
    FROM
        acc_head_mcg AS a 
    WHERE 
    (acc_type='4')) AS T1
WHERE 
    coalesce(LAmt,0)<>0
```

Query 2 is same as Query 1 except that `acc_type = '5'`  in Query 2.  Query 2 always returns a resultset with a single row. Now, I need the union of the two queries i.e

```
Query 1 
UNION
Query 2
```

only when the amt returned by Query 2 is less than 0. Else, I don't need a union but only the resulset from Query 1.

The best way I can think of is to create a parameterised scalar function. How best can I do this?

Comment: Just an observation: the `coalesce(LAmt,0) AS amt` column seems redundant because of the `coalesce(LAmt,0)<>0` condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could store the result of the first query into a temporary table, then, if the table wasn't empty, execute the other query.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MultipleQueriesResults') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #MultipleQueriesResults;

SELECT
    acc_code, acc_name, alias, LAmt, coalesce(LAmt,0) AS amt 
INTO #MultipleQueriesResults
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        acc_code, acc_name, alias, 
        (SELECT 
            (SUM(cr_amt)-SUM(dr_amt)) 
        FROM 
            ledger_mcg l
        WHERE 
            (l.acc_code LIKE a.acc_code + '.%' OR l.acc_code=a.acc_code) 
        AND 
            fy_id=1 
        AND
            posted_date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2011-06-02') AS LAmt 
    FROM
        acc_head_mcg AS a 
    WHERE 
    (acc_type='4')) AS T1
WHERE 
    coalesce(LAmt,0)<>0;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #MultipleQueriesResults)
  … /* run Query 2 */
```

Comment: Well there was a slight change in requirements and so was the query itself too. But your ans is still helpful to me.